# Can $\sqrt{3}$ be written as a polynomial expression in $\sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\zeta_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity, splitting-field

I believe that it cannot be done. But now I can only think of the method using the basis of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]{3})$, which is brute force and tedious. So I am now searching for a rather simple method. Could someone please tell me if there is some simple method? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The field $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]3)$ has degree $6$ over $\Bbb Q$
and Galois group $S_3$. It has a unique quadratic subfield, $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: I see, but how can we conclude that $\sqrt{3}\notin \Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$ then? Is the only way still using basis?

Comment: Does it follows from $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})$ is real?

Comment: @non-abeliangroupoforder9 If it did then $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$ and one is a real and the other isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Galois theory provides a roundabout way of doing this.  Consider the following lemma:

**Lemma**: If $K/F$ is a Galois extension, then the minimal polynomial in $F[x]$ for any $a \in K$ has as its roots the elements in the orbit of $a$ under the action of $\text{Gal}(K/F)$.  That is, if $S = \{ \phi(a) \ | \ \phi \in \text{Gal}(K/F) \}$, then $\displaystyle \min_a(x) = \prod_{u_k \in S} (x-u_k)$.

*Proof*: This is a consequence of the fact that a polynomial is irreducible $\iff$ its Galois group acts [transitively](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitiveGroupAction.html) on its roots.  For a proof of this fact, see Theorem 2.9(b) [**here**](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisaspermgp.pdf).  Notice that $\displaystyle \min_a(x)$ will be an irreducible polynomial (by definition), and its Galois group will be a subgroup of $\text{Gal}(K/F)$.  This latter fact is because, if $L \subseteq K$ is the splitting field of $\displaystyle \min_a(x)$, every $F$-automorphism of $L$ [extends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_extension_theorem) to an $F$-automorphism of $K$. $\qquad \blacksquare$

---

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}, \zeta_3)$.  Note $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension since finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are separable, and it is the splitting field for $f(x) = x^3 - 3$.  Now assume $\sqrt{3} \in K$.  Because we know the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}$ to be quadratic, the orbit of $\sqrt{3}$ under the action of $\text{Gal}(K/F)$ should have two elements per the lemma.What is $\text{Gal}(K/F)$?  It is a $6$-element group $\cong S_3$ generated by the following two automorphisms: complex conjugation and $\sigma$ defined where $\sqrt[3]{3} \mapsto \zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{3}$.

Clearly complex conjugation fixes $\sqrt{3}$. If $\sigma$ does not fix $\sqrt{3}$, it is necessarily sent to $-\sqrt{3}$.  But $\sigma$ has order $3$, i.e. $\sigma^3 = \text{id}$, whereas we would have $\sigma^3(\sqrt{3}) = - \sqrt{3}$.  Not possible.  So $\sqrt{3}$ is fixed by every element of $\text{Gal}(K/F)$, which implies $g(x) = x - \sqrt{3}$ is its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$.

This is a contradiction arising from our assumption that $\sqrt{3} \in K$.  We can conclude $\sqrt{3} \notin K$.

Comment: How do you know the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}$ is quadratic? Doesn't this assume $\sqrt{3} \not \in K$?

Comment: @mathworker21, $x^2 - 3$ has $\sqrt{3}$ as a root, and it's irreducible per Eisenstein.  Why would that preclude $\sqrt{3} \in K$?  For instance, $i\sqrt{3} \in K$, and it's minimal polynomial is quadratic.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant the minimal polynomial in $K[x]$